How to extend a User's profile to save data in Django
I'm new to Django and I'm attempting to build a website where a user can view a DB of books and related authors and add any book to their 'favourites'. I've been searching lots and I can't find a satisfactory way of doing this - or indeed of saving any user data other than customising fields when you create a user.
My current idea is to extend the UserModel to add an extra field which links their favourite book to the user. Tips on UserModel found here
I can now see the UserProfile with some favourites by logging in to the Admin account, but I cannot link the View class/function with my bookfavs.html for the User to see their favourited books. The bookfavs.html states the username but not favourites.
readable_project  app_name = bookshelf
Models.py
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Book, related_name='favourites')

class Author(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    dob = models.DateField()
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('authorlist')

class Book(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    num_page = models.IntegerField()
    date_pub = models.DateField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blurb = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('')`


views.py
#Add favourite button...?
def favorite(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        favorite = Book.objects.get(pk=pk)
        user = request.user
        user.favorites.add(favorite)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Book Favorited.')
        return redirect('home')


#List ALL books
class BookList(ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name='bookshelf/booklist.html'

#List favourite books
class BookFavs(TemplateView):
    model = UserProfile
    template_name = 'bookshelf/bookfavs.html'
    def get_context_data(self,*args, **kwargs):
        context = super(BookFavs, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
        context['users'] = UserProfile.objects.all()
        return context

bookfavs.html
{% if user.username %} 
<h4 class="header-greet">Welcome {{ user.username }} to your books!</h4> 
{% endif %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    {% with userprofile.favorites.all as favourite_books %}
      {% for book in book_list %}
        {% if book in favorite_book %}
        <p>{{ book.title }}</p>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endwith %}
{% endif %}



Why not include the Author fields on the UserProfile. first_name and last_name are by the way already part of the User model.

i would recommend not updating the user model. Similar to what you've done, create a profile and link it via onetoone field to the user model. if the user is authenticated, you have the user record and from that can obtain the profile record. You can create automation around creation of the profile record to ensure it will always exist.
That said, look at manytomany fields to solve your original problem in a more structured way

Problems :

you are trying to access userprofile.favorites.all in the template but you are passing users (which is a list of all user profiles) to the template context.
in your template you are looping through book_list, but it should be favourite_books (the user's favorite books) to check if the book is in their favorites.

Code :
# List favorite books
class BookFavs(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'bookshelf/bookfavs.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        # access the current user's profile and their favorite books

        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            user_profile = self.request.user.userprofile
            context['favorite_books'] = user_profile.favorites.all()
        return context

You can change your bookfavs.html according to new context with some extra messages:
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <h4>Welcome {{ user.username }}! Here are your favorited books:</h4>

  <ul>
    {% for book in favorite_books %}
      <li>{{ book.title }}</li>

    <div>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'favorite' book.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if book in user.userprofile.favorites.all %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Unfavorite</button>
    {% else %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Favorite</button>
    {% endif %}
    </form>
    </div>

    {% empty %}
      <p>You have no favorite books yet.</p>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% else %}
  <p>Please log in to view your favorite books.</p>
{% endif %}

Lets Tweak Fav button function to work that way : 1. remember to cross check whether he/she is logged in or not
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages

@login_required
def favorite(request, pk):
    book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
    user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

    if book in user_profile.favorites.all():
        user_profile.favorites.remove(book)
        messages.info(request, f'"{book.title}" has been removed from your favorites.')
    else:
        user_profile.favorites.add(book)
        messages.success(request, f'"{book.title}" has been added to your favorites.')

    #  ensures the user is redirected to the same page they came from or you can go for your own implementation
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', 'home'))

I have added form in html accordingly. Dont forget to add a url for that in your urls.py
path('favorite/<int:pk>/', favorite, name='favorite')


Yuvraj, thank you so much for your response. I used your suggested code and I got the error message " django 'User' object has no attribute 'userprofile' "    I tweaked my UserProfile to change from models.ForeignKey to models.OneToOne which has done the trick and the book favourites view works now, thank you!

I still need to tweak the following function to use with a button in the full book list to 'favourite' a particular book. I can only add a favourite in the admin section of UserProfile at the moment.      #views.py
#Add favourite button...?
def favorite(request, pk):
if request.method == 'POST':
favorite = Book.objects.get(pk=pk)
user = request.user
user.favorites.add(favorite)
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Book Favorited.')
return redirect('home')

Most welcome Steve, I've added the tweaked function in my answer.
